¿Como dar formato a un archivo de texto con python?
No logro desde Python generar un archivo txt con el formato que se muestra en la imagen de fondo negro partiendo de la información que esta en excel. Las peculiaridades de este formato, es que solo permite 10 columnas de datos y cada columna tiene un tamaño, por tanto en el caso de 20 datos, se debe adaptar estos 20 puntos, los primeros 10 puntos y luego los segundos 10 puntos. El problema es obtener la estructura del archivo en si.Con respecto a la información, es una tabla con datos que representan 3 dimensiones. Distancia, profundidad-1, profundidad-2 ... etc.y para cada profundidad hay dos valores de velocidad una superior y otra inferior. Es decir, cada profundidad siempre tendrá dos valores de velocidad una superior y otra inferior, lo cual, cada set de datos son un grupo de 4, distancia, profundidad, velocidad1 y velocidad2. Los valores de distancia siempre serán los mismos para todos los valores de profundidad y velocidad.
Los datos de excel, pueden cambiar numéricamente y lo que genera dificultad es que aumente el set de datos, es decir, una nueva profundidad y sus dos respectivos valores de velocidad. Con respecto a la distancia siempre sera la misma, como se muestra en la tabla de excel, para una distancia se corresponden todos los demás valores.
El mayor reto esta en la primera columna del archivo de salida, ya que tiene espacios vacíos, lo bueno es que es periódico, cada 2 filas hay una espacio en blanco, ademas en esta columna esta un indicativo que es 1, 2, 3 ... etc, este representa el indicador del set de datos (distancia, profundidad y velocidad-1 velocidad-2). Para indicar que se va a cambiar  de set de datos se utiliza el cero, de esta forma los siguientes datos corresponde al próximo set de datos (distancia, profundidad y velocidades). Intente generar el archivo con "numpy.savetxt" el cual guarda una matriz en un archivo de texto y se puede aplicar un formato, pero este método no permite ningún espacio en blanco dentro de la matriz.
Presento el código que aplico en matlab, pero no logro replicarlo en python
f_m10='%2d %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f \n'; % 10 puntos

f_m10d='%2d %7d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d \n'; % 10 puntos

    uno=ones(1,10);
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,kpa,capas{kpa}(1:10,1));
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,kpa,capas{kpa}(1:10,2));
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10d,'',uno);
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,kpa,capas{kpa}(11:20,1));
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,0,capas{kpa}(11:20,2));
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10d,'',uno);
    %=======================================
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,kpa,capas{kpa}(1:10,1));
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,kpa,uno.*Vel_agua);
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10d,'',uno);
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,kpa,capas{kpa}(11:20,1));
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,0,uno.*Vel_agua);
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10d,'',uno);
    %=======================================
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,kpa,capas{kpa}(1:10,1));
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,kpa,uno.*Vel_agua);
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10d,'',uno);
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,kpa,capas{kpa}(11:20,1));
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10,0,uno.*Vel_agua);
    fprintf(vel_in,f_m10d,'',uno);

===============



Hola, no queda claro cual es el formato de entrada, el necesario de salida y el código que estás utilizando para guardar el archivo. Si te exporta con una columna indeseada, favor editar el post para poder entender
